# Dynamic nested message types in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java, dynamic-schema

I have a use case where the incoming payload follows a top level schema and a nested schema. There can be 4 types of top level schema and infinite types of nested schema. I want to define my top level schemas in such a way that the internal schema can correspond to any message type in a directory. Is that possible with protobuf? If yes, how? And how would the decoding happen in such case

E.g.

```
message topLevelMessage {
 string field1 = 1;
 string field2 = 2;
 string schemaType = 3;
 schemaType payload = 4;
}
```

I have tried researching and the best response I have gotten so far is to use `map` in protobuf which I'd rather not do

---

Edit: I'd also like to do something like below

```
message topLevelMessage {
 string field1 = 1;
 string field2 = 2;
 string schemaType = 3;
 repeated schemaType|messageType2|messageType3 payload = 4;
}
```

The motivation here is to make it easier to migrate our legacy service. Thereforce, there's less wiggle room

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to read the [Protocol Buffer](https://protobuf.dev/) documentation as most concepts are well-explained.

You can use Google's [Well-known Types](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/) [`Any`](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#any) to embed (arbitrary|open-ended set of) protobuf messages.

**But** prototype this approach before you commit to it as it introduces complexity.

For union types (`schemaType|messageType2|messageType3`), you can use [`Oneof`](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#oneof).